# Tile request limits at {a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles

My in-house application is using the OpenStreetMap tile servers `{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org` for a 'free' base layer. I've read [the tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) and although it prohibits "heavy use" it only provides a vague reference to what this might be.

Users within the company office periodically see a slow down in tile performance (e.g. suddenly each tile takes 10 - 15 seconds to download). This happens for map areas they use on a regular basis (it's unlikely the tiles are being generated on-the-fly) and it doesn't happen for remote users (who access the tile servers from a different origin IP). This suggests that the tile servers are throttling performance based on origin IP.

I found [some source code](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/mod_tile.conf) in the OpenStreetMap Github mod_tile repo that supports throttling based on IP but 1) I'm not sure if this is what is used at `{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org` and 2) I still have no idea what the usage limits are.

Are there defined and published limits on how many tiles per (day|week|month) a single IP may request?

Answer (score 2):

Even if there are specific limits they can change any time. Also specific applications/users might get blocked explicitly if they put too much stress on the servers, independently of these limits. Remember that the goal of OpenStreetMap is *not* to provide free map *tiles* for everyone. OpenStreetMap is about free map *data*.

The [Tile Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) you mentioned suggests to contact the [system administrators](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/System_Administrators) or to ask at the [OSM IRC channel](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IRC). This is either #osm or #osm-dev at irc.oftc.net.

If your company needs to access lots of tiles then consider [running your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: While a valid suggestion this doesn't answer the question. At this point I'm trying to verify if the slow-down is likely due to rate-limiting or if it could be a different problem with an intermediary. Knowing if and when rate-limiting is enforced will help me reach a conclusion.